# Unity - Indentificar textura em local X Y do terrain

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tenho um terrain na unity, e queria saber se tem alguma maneira de identificar qual é a textura em certa posição XY no terrain. Exemplo:

[image]

Comment: Tavez isso ajude http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/456973/getting-the-texture-of-a-certain-point-on-terrain.html

Comment: @MurariAlex ajudou bastante, vlw!

Comment: @MurariAlex Por que você não posta uma resposta baseada no link que sugeriu?